# Combining log terms

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I have this particular problem. We have to combine the log terms into a single log term:

$$\dfrac{(2\ln a- \ln b - 5\ln c)}{2}$$

I did it in the following way :

$$''~= \ln a -\frac{1}{2}\ln b - \frac{5}{2} \ln c$$
$$= \ln\left(\left(\frac{a^2c^5}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Is this correct approach?

I used the formula : $\log_ba-\log_bc=\log_b\left(\dfrac{a}{c}\right)$

Comment: Not quite.  The $c^5$ belongs in the denominator.

Comment: $c$ ought to be in the denominator.

Comment: Thank you but why? isnt it the form of $a/b/c$ which equals $ac/b$ ?

Comment: Try it with $-ln(x) = + ln(\frac{1}{x})$. And in general, as a visual aid, all the positives will go in the numerator, and the negatives in the denominator.

Comment: Ah! This might be your error... $\ln a - \ln b  -\ln c \ne \ln a - \ln\frac{b}{c}$. Why? Consider: $\ln a - (\ln b  + \ln c) = \ln a - \ln bc = \ln\frac{a}{bc}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{(2\ln a- \ln b - 5\ln c)}{2}$$
$$ =\dfrac{(\ln a^2- \ln b - \ln c^5)}{2} $$
$$= \dfrac{\left(\ln \dfrac{a^2}{b} - \ln c^5\right)}{2} $$
$$= \dfrac{1}{2}\ln \dfrac{a^2}{bc^5}  $$
$$= \ln \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{bc^5}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and answer! This was really confusing! :)

Comment: is there a good resource (book etc) for learning logarithms?

Comment: You may want to dig into Khan Academy - lots of video tutorials. As for a book, try Precalculus by Young (Ch3 for exponential and logs).


  [1]: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/logarithms-tutorial